# Scikit-surprise import not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have tried installing scikit-surprise using the following command

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise
```

But when running the import on my jupyter notebook

```
from surprise import Dataset
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surprise'
```

I'm currently using Python 3.11.4 on Windows 10 and tried to reinstall the kit several times

Comment: How did you insure that it was installing to the proper environment where you are running your Jupyter Notebook? If you don't want to take the time to sort that out, you can try running in your notebook where you want to try the import statement `%conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise`. Let it run completely and then restart the kernel. Then try running the import statement.

Comment: That magic install command I suggested insures it installs to the correct environment where the kernel is running that underlies your active `.ipynb` file. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about it. It is the modern best practice for installing from within the running notebook using Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager.